# How to Parse Json to get value from "sub-column"?

Tags: json, autoit

The column and sub-column are different for each set.

I need to read column `"24"`. Then read sub-column `"11"` (but not `"6"` or any other) and get `"value": 1.66"`. I can't get AutoIt to read it.

My Json file:

```
"24": {
    "alt_defindex": {
        "0": 210
    },
    "11": {
        "0": {
            "value": 1.66,
            "last_change": -0.17,
            "last_update": 1390231504
        }
    },
    "6": {
        "0": {
            "value": 1,
            "last_change": -0.17,
            "last_update": 1382770803
        }
    }
},
"30": {
    "alt_defindex": {
        "0": 212
    },
    "11": {
        "0": {
            "value": 22.75,
            "last_change": 1.75,
            "last_update": 1389765935
        }
    },
    "6": {
        "0": {
            "value": 0.94,
            "last_change": 0.28,
            "last_update": 1367126509
        }
    }
},
"35": {
    "11": {
        "0": {
            "value": 346.5,
            "last_change": 59.5,
            "last_update": 1390149299
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "0": {
            "value": 0.33,
            "last_change": -0.11,
            "last_update": 1379423777
        }
    },
    "6": {
        "0": {
            "value": 0.05,
            "last_change": 0,
            "last_update": 1336410088
        }
    },
    "600": {
        "0": {
            "value": 0.05,
            "last_change": 0.03,
            "last_update": 1362791812
        }
    }
},
"36": {
    "11": {
        "0": {
            "value": 2.33,
            "last_change": 0.17,
            "last_update": 1386034870
        }
    },
    "14": {
        "0": {
            "value": 73.5,
            "last_change": 73.5,
            "last_update": 1389414784
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "0": {
            "value": 0.22,
            "last_change": -0.06,
            "last_update": 1376609090
        }
    },
    "6": {
        "0": {
            "value": 0.05,
            "last_change": 0,
            "last_update": 1336410089
        }
    },
    "600": {
        "0": {
            "value": 0.04,
            "last_change": -0.01,
            "last_update": 1381960202
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: There are no columns in JSON. There are attributes and values. "24" is the attribute. It's value is an object which contains other attributes e.g. "11".

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON string is wrong.

```
Parse error on line 1:
"24": {    "alt_def
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Use this site to check your JSON.

http://jsonlint.com/